# Python: Renumerate elements in multiple lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Suppose I have a dictionary with lists as follows:

```
{0: [31, 32, 58, 59], 1: [31, 32, 12, 13, 37, 38], 2: [12, 13]}
```

I am trying to obtain the following one from it:

```
{0: [1, 2, 3, 4], 1: [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8], 2: [5, 6]}
```

So I renumerate all the entries in order of occurence but skipping those that were already renumerated.

What I have now is a bunch of for loops going back and forth which works, but doesn't look good at all, could anyone please tell me the way it should be done in Python 2.7?

Thank you

Comment: Note that dictionaries are unordered, so having one list of values processed before another list of values is undefined unless you go out of your way to process them in an order (for example in order of sorted keys)

Comment: Your dictionary doesn't have order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import operator
data = {0: [31, 32, 58, 59], 1: [31, 32, 12, 13, 37, 38], 2: [12, 13]}


# the accumulator is the new dict with renumbered values combined with a list of renumbered numbers so far
# item is a (key, value) element out of the original dict
def reductor(acc, item):
   (out, renumbered) = acc
   (key, values)     = item
   def remapper(v):
       try:
           x = renumbered.index(v)
       except ValueError:
           x = len(renumbered)
           renumbered.append(v)
       return x
   # transform current values to renumbered values
   out[key] = map(remapper, values)
   # return output and updated list of renumbered values
   return (out, renumbered)

# now reduce the original data
print reduce(reductor, sorted(data.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(0)), ({}, []))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a function like this:

```
def renumerate(data):
    ids = {}
    def getid(val):
        if val not in ids:
            ids[val] = len(ids) + 1
        return ids[val]
    return {k : map(getid, data[k]) for k in sorted(data.keys())}
```

#### Example

```
>>> data = {0: [31, 32, 58, 59], 1: [31, 32, 12, 13, 37, 38], 2: [12, 13]}
>>> print renumerate(data)
{0: [1, 2, 3, 4], 1: [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8], 2: [5, 6]}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not worried about memory or speed you can use an intermediate dictionary to map the new values:

```
a = {0: [31, 32, 58, 59], 1: [31, 32, 12, 13, 37, 38], 2: [12, 13]}
b = {}
c = {}

for key in sorted(a.keys()):
    c[key] = [b.setdefault(val, len(b)+1) for val in a[key]]
```

Comment: I would use `b.setdefault(val, len(b))` but otherwise, nice.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {0: [31, 32, 58, 59], 1: [31, 32, 12, 13, 37, 38], 2: [12, 13]}

from collections import defaultdict
numbered = defaultdict(lambda: len(numbered)+1)


result = {key: [numbered[v] for v in val] for key, val in sorted(data.iteritems(), key=lambda item: item[0])}
print result
```